# How to destructure Kotlin objects in streams

Tags: kotlin

In Scala, I can easily extract values from objects (e.g. tuple) using partial function:

```
list
    .zip(list.reverse)
    .foreach{case (x, y) => println(s"$x $y")}
```

How can I do that in Kotlin? It seems that destructors are supported only for assignments and for loops.

Comment: That's pattern matching not partial functions. And Kotlin doesn't support it (unfortunately).

Comment: It does work for Tuples with destructuring though. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html. We'd need some more information on what type your list is to help you though.

Comment: FYI, "partial functions" sounds like "partial application", or currying, which is something completely different and confusing in this context

Comment: @voddan I was referring to partially _defined_ function.

Comment: @ŽeljkoTrogrlić yes indeed Scala uses that term. Just googled it up. Sorry for bothering you. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At Kotlin 1.0 use an additional `val` declaration:

```
list.foreach{val (x, y) = it; println(s"$x $y")}
```

The team says they are already working on that feature (the syntax was reserved) and they hopefully will get it in Kotlin 1.1:

```
list.foreach{(x, y) -> println(s"$x $y")}
```